# HTML table checked to select rows of data

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to create an array list of values of selected rows in a table based off checkbox input. I think my problem is the pop command but I am not sure. Basically users could select row x, y, z, and see these stored in the array, then unselect z to only see x and y.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var values = new Array();

    function setrow(row)
    { 
        values = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            if (values[i] = row) {
               values.pop(i);

            } else {
              values.push(row);
            }
        }
    } 


    function display() {
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            console.log(values[i]);
        }    
    }

</script> 

<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1> 
<tr id="r1"> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="rctrl" onclick="return setrow('r1')"></td>
    <td>text</td> 
</tr> 

<tr id="r2"> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="rctrl" onclick="return setrow('r2')"></td>
    <td>text</td> 
</tr> 

<tr id="r3"> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="rctrl" onclick="return setrow('r3')"></td>
    <td>text</td> 
</tr> 

<tr id="r4"> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="rctrl" onclick="return setrow('r4')"></td>
    <td>text</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 

<button type="button" onClick="display()">Click</button>
```

Comment: How about formatting your code with proper indentation.

Comment: And then run it through a code validator so you can discover the misplaced assignment.

Comment: And maybe treat an Array like an Array instead of a plain Object.

Comment: Well your first mistake is this line `if (values['r' + i] = row){`. You're doing an assignment instead of a comparison. It should be `==` instead of `=`. That aside I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.pop`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.6) doesn't take any arguments, it just removes and returns the last element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be much simpler to store the value of each checkbox in an object, using r* as the keys:

```
var values = {};

function setrow(checkbox, row)
{ 
    values[row] = checkbox.checked;
} 


function display() {
    console.log(values);  
}​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4TjhZ/

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple issues.

1. You're setting your `values` array to an empty array every time you
   call `setrow()`
2. Because you're starting your loop at 1, you'll never iterate through your first array item.
3. the `pop()` method automatically removes the last item in the array.  It doesn't take a parameter like you're using it.  You'd need to use the [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method: `splice(i, 1)`
4. Your `if` statement should use a `==` or `===` (as a comparison) instead of `=` (setter)

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

```
var values = new Array();
```

Most use an array literal as it's less to type and the constructor can be confusing, so:

```
var values = [];
```

.

```
function setrow(row)
{ 
    values = [];
```

Oops, you just assigned a new array instance to values.

```
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (values[i] = row) {
           values.pop(i);
```

`pop` doesn't take any arguments, it just removes and returns the last member of the array.

Presumably you want an array of the checked rows, so why not put a click listener on the table and update the array whenever it gets a click, e.g.

```
<table onclick="updateArray(this);" ...>
```

then the function:

```
var values;
function updateArray(table) {
  var arr = [];
  var rctrls = document.getElementsByName('rctrl');
  var el, row;

  for (var i=0, iLen=rctrls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    el = rctrls[i];

    if (el.checked) {
      arr.push(el.parentNode.parentNode);
    }
  }
}
```

You could get a bit more sophisticated and us a function that goes from the input up to the first row element, e.g.

```
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  var el;
  do {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  } while (el.parentNode)
}
```

Then do:

```
    if (el.checked) {
      row = upTo(el, 'tr');
      if (row) {
        arr.push(row);
      }
    }
```